# mysql single column values to multiple columns group by another column value

Tags: mysql

i am trying to  create a query from a table looking like this

```
timestamp             |         iddebi       | value 
========================================================
2018-02-17  14:29:00             1               901
2018-02-19  14:29:00             1               501
2018-02-20  14:29:00             1               301
2018-02-21  14:29:00             1               501
2018-02-18  14:29:00             2               301
2018-02-19  14:29:00             2               401
2018-02-20  14:29:00             2               601
2018-02-21  14:29:00             2               701
2018-02-18  14:29:00             3               901
2018-02-19  14:29:00             3               501
2018-02-20  14:29:00             3               301
2018-02-21  14:29:00             3               501
```

i want to select values between dates , group them by date, and id on separated columns

```
timestamp            |  iddebi_1  |  iddebi_2  | iddebi_3
===========================================================
2018-02-17  14:29:00     901         null        null
2018-02-18  14:29:00     null         301        901
2018-02-19  14:29:00     501         401        501
2018-02-20  14:29:00     301         601        301
2018-02-21  14:29:00     501         701        501
```

so, i want the values of different ids grouped by columns (based on id )
and where there is no value to return null
thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

```
select timestamp,
       max(case when iddebi = 1 then value else null end) as iddebi_1,
       max(case when iddebi = 2 then value else null end) as iddebi_2,
       max(case when iddebi = 3 then value else null end) as iddebi_3
from your_table
group by timestamp
```